# Flutter fresh installation can't run on android

Tags: android, flutter, keystore, android-keystore

### Disclaimer

i got this issue when i had android studio installed, i've been using android studio for a while before i got this issue. and  i'm trying to uninstalling android studio to save some of my storage and manually install android emulator, still facing the same issue.

### Description

my flutter app scan keystore in the wrong directory when try to run in android emulator, my app keystore located at
`/Users/saidulumam/Documents/Projects/flutter/tome/android/~/Library/Android/Sdk/.android/debug.keystore`
but it scans
`/Users/saidulumam/Documents/Projects/flutter/tome/android/app/~/Library/Android/Sdk/.android/debug.keystore`

### Steps to Reproduce

1. go to project folder
2. type `flutter create app_name` in this case im using name `tome`
3. type `cd tome`
4. type `flutter run`
5. error

### Screenshot

[image]

my directory
[image]

### Logs

Error result :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageDebug' (type 'PackageApplication').
> File '/Users/saidulumam/Documents/Projects/flutter/tome/android/app/~/Library/Android/Sdk/.android/debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             33.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor :

```
➜  tome flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command for specifying  android sdk path to flutter :

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

Comment: yes i have it on the bottom of my post

Comment: @MuhammadSaidulUmam : check edited answer

Comment: i tried it, and still have the same issue,

Comment: this is my full command
```➜ flutter config --android-sdk $ANDROID_SDK_HOME ```
and the output is
```Setting "android-sdk" value to "~/Library/Android/Sdk"```

Comment: What was that tom ?

Comment: sorry that is my directory

Comment: okay fine. can try again for same by flutter clean  , flutter pub get and re run app

Comment: still not work.

Comment: Can you share or check local.properties file for sdk.dir if its has  ~/Library/Android/Sdk then  its taking ~ as your project

Comment: ```sdk.dir=/Users/saidulumam/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/saidulumam/Documents/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1```

Comment: sorry, this is clear screenshot of local.properties https://dropover.cloud/715b2d